# webservice...cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: java, android, web-services

Im trying to implement a web service for an android app (with Phonegap)

I have an Interface:

```
package webservice;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService

public interface HelloService {
@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(String name);
```

}

and the implementation of it:

```
package webservice;
import javax.jws.*;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.phonegap.DroidGap;

@WebService
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

    //Constructor for a invocation with javascript
public LottozahlenServiceImpl(DroidGap gap, WebView view){

}

public String hello(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello "+name);
     return "Hello "+name +" Welcome to Web Services!";
}
```

}
The problem is, all imports and the annotation "cannot be resolved as a type". I downloaded [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2) and added the JAR to the build path. I also restarted Eclipse, cleaned the project, reloaded the target. I cant solve this. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Implement a webservice? Consume it? Both? Android doesn't include the JEE stack afaik, you can't implement web services in it.

Comment: I want to implement it. I want to consume it later by calling the method from my phonegap application.

Comment: You need to implement your web service in a separate JEE project and run it under a web application container. Then you can consume it from your Android/PhoneGap application, using ksoap or whatever other libraries fits your fancy.

Comment: of course, I did not realise that I have to implement my Service on a Server. Stupid me. Thank you Perception!

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked in Eclipse

select your project
→ then right click on project menu bar on top
→ go to properties
→ click on Targeted Runtimes
→ now you must select a check box next to the server you are using to run current project
→ click Apply
→ then click OK button.

That's it, give a try.